# Model with money-rails testing using RSpec new syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec3, money-rails

New to Ruby on Rails here.

I'm doing an application with money support using [money-rails gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails). I want to test the money locale.

Reading the [gem's example at test_helpers_spec.rb](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/blob/master/spec/test_helpers_spec.rb), there is

```
let(:product) do
  Product.create(:price_cents => 3000, :discount => 150,
    :bonus_cents => 200,
    :sale_price_amount => 1200)
end

...

describe "monetize matcher" do
  ...

  it "matches model attribute with currency specified by :with_currency chain" do
    product.should monetize(:bonus_cents).with_currency(:gbp)
  end

  ...
end
```

where the respective [Product model](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails/blob/master/spec/dummy/app/models/product.rb#L15) has

```
monetize :bonus_cents, :with_currency => :gbp
```

so the test passes. How would I would rewrite that test following the recent [rspec's expect(...)](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations) syntax? I would try

```
expect(monetize(:bonus_cents).with_currency(:gbp)).to be true
```

but it fails.

Comment: try: `expect(product).to monetize(:bonus_cents).with_currency(:gbp)`

Comment: and you shouldn't testing gem functionality, because it's already tested

Comment: @IS04 not doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
product.should monetize(:bonus_cents).with_currency(:gbp)
```

Comes out to:

```
expect(product).to monetize(:bonus_cents).with_currency(:gbp)
```

`expect` just wraps the object being tested, the rest of the matchers are generally the same.